# PHP GD sharpness filter

Tags: php, image-processing, filter, gd

How can you make a sharpness filter with the **PHP GD** library?

**So that this...**

[image]

**Turns to this...**

[image]

If it is not possible with **PHP**, than what other languages are capable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think he wants to use PHP's GD library. It's pretty easy: [function.imageconvolution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php). Just search for 'sharpen' on the page and you'll see a matrix you can use for sharpening. It works pretty well, although I would recommend using ImageMagick if you're trying to do anything more than that.

Answer (score 5):

If the ImageMagick is installed in your PHP config, you can use `Imagick::adaptiveSharpenImage`

From the manual:

```
<?php
try {
    $image = new Imagick('image.png');
    $image->adaptiveSharpenImage(2,1);
} catch(ImagickException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' , $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-adaptivesharpenimage.php

Answer (score 4):

There is a library called Unsharp Mask PHP, which does exactly what you need.
http://vikjavev.no/computing/ump.php

Answer (score 0):

For **GD**: This is the function I am using:

```
function sharpen($gdImage) {
    // Matrix
    $sharpen = array(
        array(0.0, -0.5, 0.0),
        array(-0.5, 5, -0.5),
        array(0.0, -0.5, 0.0)
    );

    // Calculate the sharpen divisor
    $divisor = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $sharpen));

    // Apply matrix
    imageconvolution($image, $sharpen, $divisor, 0);
    return $image;
}
```

Example:

```
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");
$im = sharpen($im);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
```