# How to sharpening an uploaded image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

How to sharpening an uploaded image in PHP ?

Is there some PHP libraries ? What is the best ?

Comment: -1 Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576550/php-gd-sharpness-filter

Comment: @x3ro that doesn't call for a downvote, but for a close vote as duplicate.

Comment: Yep, but I can't do that, as far as I know. Not enough rep... And imho its a downvote, because he could've easily found it by searching stackoverflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) offers best quality and lot of other features. Use [`adaptiveSharpenImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-adaptivesharpenimage.php) function:

```
<?php
try
{
    $image = new Imagick('image.png');
    $image->adaptiveSharpenImage(2,1);
}
catch(ImagickException $e)
{
    echo 'Error: ' , $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.requirements.php). This [call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-adaptivesharpenimage.php) is one good solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [unsharp mask](http://vikjavev.no/computing/ump.php) for PHP. (Unsharp mask is one of the most common types of sharpening used.)

[Here's another option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php#56144) (using [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)).

Answer (score 0):

In this [PHP Manual comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php#56144), someone is referring to function [imageconvolution()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php), complete with an example.

Answer (score -2):

The most straightforward way is to use PHP's `imageXXX()` routines, such as `imagecreatefromjpeg()` etc.
For more powerful scripted image editing, consider ImageMagick, or some other scriptable image processor.

Comment: GD does not have a sharpening function.