# Unsharp mask with php

Tags: php

Is there a built-in function in php to add some extra sharpness on images? Like Photoshops unsharp mask?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP GD sharpness filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576550/php-gd-sharpness-filter)

Comment: [Unsharp mask for PHP](http://vikjavev.no/computing/ump.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest way is to use the phpThumb library. Here is a demo of the sharpen feature:

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php#x14

You can apparently also use `imageconvolution()` in the GD library (phpThumb uses either GD or ImageMagick, whichever is available):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php

Comment: Why adding a new lib is the easiest way? Not trying to play the smarta** but the GD lib also has sharping filters which is bundled in PHP by default.

Comment: For one thing it would allow you to move to ImageMagick without changing any of your code. It also gives you an easy way to modify images dynamically on the fly (without changing the original image). But it may not be easiest in your situation, depending on how you want to use GD. It's just a good tool you should be aware of.